# $http.get() Method didn't work on windows 8.1 cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-8.1

our project use angularjs $http.get() method to get JSON data. When page refresh, the method will get JSON again and get the latest data. It is working fine on android platfrom ,but it can not work on Win 8.1 application.

```
app.controller('ClimateMonitoringCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, WebUrlService) {
    var location = $stateParams.location_id;
    var url = WebUrlService.url;
    $scope.avai1 = false;
    $scope.avai2 = false;
    $scope.avai3 = false;
    $http.get(url + "GetSensorCurrentData/" + location)
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.station_no = "1309";
        $scope.sensors = response.data.GetSensorCurrentDataResult;
    });
```

Comment: Define "can not work". Also, what do you mean by "on Win 8.1 application"? Do you mean "in any browser on Windows"?

Comment: we use cordova platform to develop Windows 8.1 application, which means the desktop application. It's not a browser application and the problem is that we can get the JSON data when open the application, but can not refresh the JSON data when inside the application.

Answer (score 0):

Better to clarify your question , if you mean windows platform like browser on windows for security reasons it cannot execute get and post also ajax requests .
see your browser log console for details :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked...
```

So instead of using your browser to check the app use simulator or device .
You can also take advantages of WAMP Server.

hope it solve your problem

Comment: we use cordova platform to develop Windows 8.1 application, which means the desktop application. It's not a browser application and the problem is that we can get the JSON data when open the application, but can not refresh the JSON data when inside the application.